# How stop to showing oneSignal notification UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, onesignal

I have set up oneSignal in my app and everything is working fine in that, but I want to stop showing notification UI. is it possible do in Android?

I have setup is like this.

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init()
```